# Cannot boot off of SD card reader

Tags: boot, sd-card

I have a Asus Zenbook ux31a and my SSD just died so I am trying to run off of a SD card but cannot get it to boot off of it.

I installed Ubuntu 64 bit onto the SD using a usb flash drive and created a boot option in the bios pointing to grubx64.efi but does not recognize.

Here is the online report created for the boot-info

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9931242/

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on UEFI but looking at your link, I'm not convinced the SD card is right - it appears you have it booted from the USB-stick to obtain the report, however this:

```
$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002
Boot0001* UEFI: TOSHIBA TransMemory-Mx PMAP ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1d,0)USB(1,0)USB(1,0)HD(1,20,1d0d7e0,000e5599)AMBO
Boot0002* Hard Drive    BIOS(2,0,00)AMGOAMNO.........T.O.S.H.I.B.A. .T.r.a.n.s.M.e.m.o.r.y.-.M.x. .P.M.A.P....................A.............................L..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.T.O.S.H.I.B.A. .T.r.a.n.s.M.e.m.o.r.y.-.M.x. .P.M.A.P......AMBO

UEFI/Legacy mode:
BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled. (maybe sec-boot, Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com)


PARTITIONS & DISKS:
mmcblk0p1   : mmcblk0,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  is-maybe-EFI,   part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   not-far,    /media/ubuntu/DAEA-6B79.
mmcblk0p2   : mmcblk0,  not-sepboot,    grubenv-ok  grub2,  signed grub-efi ,   update-grub,    64, with-boot,  is-os,  not--efi--part, fstab-without-boot, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, apt-get,    grub-install,   with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   not-far,    /media/ubuntu/47ac1923-ae17-4a5b-8c00-21c1cbaa2fc0.
mmcblk0 : sda,  maybesepboot,   no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   not-far,    /mnt/boot-sav/mmcblk0.

mmcblk0 : GPT,  no-BIOS_boot,   has-maybe-EFI,  not-usb,    has-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     usb-disk,   no-os,  32 sectors * 512 bytes
```

Seems to suggest the SD isn't bootable.

I did find [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2223856) which looks similar

Comment: Yes, only way i can boot at all is through a usb flash drive that has the ubuntu startup on it. I did a full install from this flash drive to the SD card and it seemed to be successful, however when I removed the usb flash drive, my zenbook will not recognize any bootable device. I tried to add a bootable device but that did not work either.

Comment: I also grabbed another USB flash drive and did a full install on it. It boots just fine but no wifi. Seems like taking 1 step forward and 2 steps back..